# Change Location of Textbox when a button gets click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, location

Hi i have a button i want to change the location of the textbox can anyone tell me how. I tried the tb location thing that has been commented below but it still dosent work .

code is here

```
        Private Sub ExpandBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles                  ExpandBtn.Click
    expandMenu.Visible = False
    Me.Height = 345
    Me.Width = 820

   'nameTB.location = (480 , 100)
    grdDataGrid.Visible = True
    'expand it to a certain size 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you need this ...

```
nameTB.location = New Point(480 , 100)
```